# Elasticsearch Multi field mapping text + flattened

Tags: elasticsearch

Problem statement:
I want to store a json (dynamic structure) in an ES index which should allow term, match queries along with aggregations, I found that, for this use-case `flattened` is the best choice.
Along with this, I also want to have some text search capabilities on same field with some custom analyzer.

Created following field mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "myAttribute": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
                "fields": {
                    "flat": {
                        "type": "flattened"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This got created successfully in ES index.

But, when I try to create a doc, I get `mapper_parsing_exception`

---

Try 1:
With stringified JSON

```
{ 
    "myAttribute": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}
```

Exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
                "line": 2,
                "col": 20
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [myAttribute.flat] of type [flattened] in document with id '_doc_0'. Preview of field's value: '{\"key\":\"value\"}'",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
            "line": 2,
            "col": 20
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

---

Try 2:
With JSON

```
{
    "myAttribute": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

Exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse field [myAttribute] of type [text] in document with id '_doc_0'. Preview of field's value: '{key=value}'"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [myAttribute] of type [text] in document with id '_doc_0'. Preview of field's value: '{key=value}'",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason": "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 2:20"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

---

Try 3:
With stringified JSON & JSON

```
{ 
    "myAttribute": "{\"key\":\"value\"}",
    "myAttribute.flat": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

Exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
                "line": 2,
                "col": 20
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [myAttribute.flat] of type [flattened] in document with id '_doc_0'. Preview of field's value: '{\"key\":\"value\"}'",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
            "line": 2,
            "col": 20
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```